# conditional repository injection - Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dependency-injection, couchbase

I Have two repository interfaces that connect :
**MongoDB** and **CouchBase** :

```java
public interface UserRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
}
public interface UserRepositoryCouch extends  CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Is there a way to interchangeably `@Autowire` these repositories into `UserService` on a condition?
The condition will be inside property file :  `application.properties`.

```
**Note :**

*These repositories can have custom methods too.*
```

Comment: Are you having MongoDB and Couchbase active at the same time or switching between them?

Comment: no. It can be also disconnected. But I always give active one as the condition

Comment: yes, if you can use `@Profile` or if you have tried with `@Conditionalonproperty`

Comment: Have you tried just using `PagingAndSortingRepository`? If you only have one Spring Data provider active, it should automatically wire it.

Comment: PagingAndSortingRepository cannot be used there are lots of repositories in the package

Comment: I don’t know my answer is right or not but I tell my opinion, why you try factory pattern for this approach. Based on the repo you can able switch object right? I think it’s an easy way @NilankaManoj your thoughts?

Comment: This will not work. The MongoDB and Couch repositories do not have 100% CRUD syntax support. Better to use the `@Service` implementation separately. You can activate 1 of them with [@Profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another attempt to solve this problem.

Based on the property, the autowired customRepository will be an instance of SimpleMongoRepository or SimpleCouchRepository.

```
    public interface CustomRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
        User findByLastName(String lastName); //custom methods
    }

    @Qualifier("specificRepo")
    @ConditionalOnProperty("mongo.url")
    public interface UserRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<User, Long>, CustomRepository{
    }

    @Qualifier("specificRepo")   
    @ConditionalOnProperty("couch.url")
    public interface UserRepositoryCouch extends  CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>, CustomRepository{
    }

    public class UserService {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("specificRepo")
        private CustomRepository repository;
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

We can use either `ConditionalOnProperty` or `ConditionalOnExpression` to switch between two different repository implementation.

1. If we want to control the autowiring with simple property presence/absence or property value, then `ConditionalOnProperty` can be used.
2. If complex evaluation is required, then we can use `ConditionalOnExpression`.

ConditionalOnProperty (presence/absence of a property)

```
@Qualifier("specificRepo")
@ConditionalOnProperty("mongo.url")
public interface UserRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<User, Long>{
}

@Qualifier("specificRepo")   
@ConditionalOnProperty("couch.url")
public interface UserRepositoryCouch extends  CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

ConditionalOnProperty (based on value)

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("repo.url", havingValue="mongo", matchIfMissing = true) //this will be default implementation if no value is matching
public interface UserRepositoryMongo extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {
}

@ConditionalOnProperty("repo.url", havingValue="couch")
public interface UserRepositoryCouch extends  CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

ConditionalOnExpression

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{'${repository.url}'.contains('couch')}")
public interface UserRepositoryCouch extends  CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

**UPDATE**

Use `CrudRepository/Repository` type to inject based on your requirement.

```
public class DemoService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("specificRepo")
    private CrudRepository repository;
}
```

Based on bean created, either `UserRepositoryMongo` or `UserRepositoryCouch` will be autowired. Make sure only one bean is instantiated to avoid ambiguity error.

Comment: so, how I autowire this into service?

Comment: updated the answer to include injection logic as well. If you need pagination functionality, `PagingAndSortingRepository` can be used instead of `CrudRepository`

Comment: The issue is that I have other repositories in the package, This type of autowire will cause errors.

Comment: Add a marker interface if you need to use only between two of them and you can use that interface type for injection.

Comment: updated first code snippet to show what I meant in the above comment.

Comment: I tried SpecificRepository one, But it seems like, cannot use couch, mongo repo methods when autowired.

Comment: eg : repository.save not found

Comment: Understood. We can try with Qualifiers to limit the repository implementation that qualifies for CrudRepository to only two of them. Updated my answer. Hopefully other implementation should not have issues as they would have used specific Repository implementation.

Comment: Other approach I could think about, let `SpecificRepository` extend both `MongoRepository` & `CouchRepository` and change your custom repository implementations (`UserRepositoryMongo & UserRepositoryCouch`)  to extend from `SpecificRepository` so that we can use `SpecificRepository` for injection. (although it's not efficient, it would still solve your problem)

Comment: Is it possible to resolve custom methods using @qualifier?

Comment: if you need support for custom methods, then the approach in my previous comment would help.